# Job Salaries not paying out

Tags: php, cron-task

My daily job salaries seems to not be paying out, it should be paying the user according to their current held job. Can someone help me?

```
function update_salaries()
{
    $salaries = array(
        '1' => array(5000, 1),
        '2' => array(10000, 2),
        '3' => array(15000, 3),
        '4' => array(30000, 4),
        '5' => array(50000, 5),
        '6' => array(60000, 6),
        '7' => array(70000, 7),
        '8' => array(80000, 8),
        '9' => array(90000, 9),
        '10' => array(100000, 10)
    );

    foreach ($salaries as $job)
    {
        $qry = 'UPDATE user_characters SET cash=(cash + ' . $data[0] . '),misc_points=(misc_points + ' . $data[1] . ')';
        $qry .= ' WHERE ' . $job . '!=0';
        db_query($qry);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jszobody +1. When you find an answer to that, please fix mine too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want it like this:

```
foreach ($salaries as $jobID => $job)
{
    $qry = "UPDATE user_characters 
            SET cash=(cash + {$job[0]}),
            misc_points=(misc_points + {$job[1]})
            WHERE jobId = {$jobID}";
    db_query($qry);
}
```

Error reporting and printing your query would have helped you.

Comment: ERROR: [1054] Unknown column 'jobId' in 'where clause' :: UPDATE user_characters 
SET cash=(cash + 5000),
misc_points=(misc_points + 1)
WHERE jobId = 1

Comment: Well, what column do you store their job level in?

Comment: job in user_characters :)

Comment: So use some basic reasoning and fix the query.